# Flatlist not scrolling all the way, or at all

Tags: react-native

Flatlist wont scroll at all. I have looked at other answers but to no help.

If i comment out flexDirection and justifyContent in the "container" style in Item.js, it scrolls a little bit but still not all the way. Also if i have to comment these out i dont know how i can make the button stick to the right side.

App.js

```
return (
        <View>
            
            <View>

            <FlatList
                data={list}
                renderItem={({item}) => (
                    <Item deleteFunction={deleteItem} content={item}/>
                )}       
            />
            </View>
                
            
            
        </View>
    )
```

Item.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'

export default function Item({content, deleteFunction}) {
    
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{content.name}</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => deleteFunction(content.key)} style={styles.touch}>
                <Text style={styles.button}>
                    X
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        // padding: 10,
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderColor: "black",
        marginHorizontal: 60,
        marginBottom: 15,
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: "space-between",

        
    },
    touch: {
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
        // backgroundColor: "pink"
    },
    text:{
        paddingVertical: 10,
        maxWidth: 240,

    },
    button:{
        color: "red",
        paddingVertical: 10,
        maxWidth: 200
    }


})
```

Comment: Add style to flat list contentContainerStyle ={{flexGrow:1}}

Answer (score 0):

Add bottom padding to the view file in the App.js

```
return (
        <View>
            
            <View style={{bottomPadding: 20}}>

            <FlatList
                data={list}
                renderItem={({item}) => (
                    <Item deleteFunction={deleteItem} content={item}/>
                )}       
            />
            </View>
                
            
            
        </View>
    )
```

This might work.